# Unsure how to post form data in Unit Test

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a HTML template which submits a form containing the results of a user selection. This form is posted to a python function in "routes.py" which adds to a database, based on the value of this selection. I am trying to run a unit test on this function, however do not know how to post the form within the unit tests file.

Here is the relevant part of the form in the HTML template:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('select') }}">
    <div class="info">

        <div >
            <div >
                <span>Select a car</span>
                <br/>
                <br>
                    <select name="car_select">
                        {% for i in cars %}
                            <option>{{i}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}    
                    </select>

            </div>
            <br><br>

            <button type="submit" onclick="time()">Vote</button>

        </div>
</form>
```

Here is the relevant part of my function in "routes.py", that I am running the unit test on:

```
@app.route("/select" , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def select():
    select = request.form.get('car_select')
```

Here is the Helper Function that I have used in my unit test to initiate the "select" function (INCORRECT):

```
def select(self, car):
        return self.app.post("/select", data=dict(car_select=car), follow_redirects = True)
```

What I expect this Helper Function to do, is simulate the POST performed by the HTML form method, such that "request.form.get('car_select')" is equal to the "car" parameter of the helper function.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `flask`'s built-in [`test_client`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/):

```py
app.test_client().post("/select", data=dict(car_select=car))
```